# Changing CSS for portrait screens (for example, iPad)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've built a website, and I'm happy it's responsiveness. However, on an ipad in portrait mode there is a large amount of white space in the bottom half and I'm wondering if there is a method to detect portrait oriented screens and change the CSS accordingly.

If someone can point me in the right direction it would be hugely appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* Portrait */
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
/* Portrait styles */
}
/* Landscape */
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
/* Landscape styles */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'll test this out and let you know how I get on. Again thanks!!

Comment: Well that was outstandingly easy!!

Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Well you could just detect screen width and height. If the height is greater than widths, then it's portrait.

```
if (window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth) {
    //Portrait code here
}
```